# Angularjs directive create click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have simple directive, like this:

```
    angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.customer = {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
      };

$scope.clicke = function(){
alert('test');
};

    }])
    .directive('myCustomer', function() {
      return {
        templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
      };
    });
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div my-customer click-event='clicke()'></div>
</div>
```

my-customer.html

```
Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}
<button>click</button>
```

and I would like create event for click to button, and after it in my controller
use this event.
But I don't know how to do it.
Help me pls. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use `ng-click`, no?

Comment: Is the entire directive supposed to be clickable? As in, is it an element directive?

Comment: `ng-click="clicke($event)"`

Comment: @ElliottRoche yes this directive supposed to be clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using something Angular already gives you: [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick).

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bibewohuwi/edit?html,js,output) example that I did for you:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div my-customer ng-click='clicke()'></div>
</div>
```

If you click on the directive, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: ok, thanks but if I need use more elements and get some id or name after click. I would like use directive like tab menu and dynamic build it. And after click to some item (1,3 .. xxx) get him id. And  I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-repeat` to iterate over an array of customers and then have your `ng-click` function take parameters assocaited to which customer (index in the array) is being displayed...

```
<div ng-repeat="customer customers track by $index" ng-click="myClickHandler(index)">
  {{customer}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following solution. A working example can be found at - 
[@sumit Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NmNMs5CguP3VpH4jgtRE?p=preview)

Here's a code sample:

```
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };

    $scope.clicke = function(evt) {
      alert('test');
    };

  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
    }
  })
  .directive('clickEvent', function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        var expressionHandler = $parse(attrs.clickEvent)
        el.find('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
          expressionHandler(scope);
        })
      }
    }
  });
```